# Rails: double render error in actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, devise

I'm new in Rails world, but this **Double render error** a little bit interesting. I have never met this problem in PHP or in ASP.NET.

So I have two actions in one controller which is extended via Devise's Register controller.
I want to achieve that If the user logged in the two `new_with_school` and `create_with_school` actions will be redirected by the `redirect_signed_in_user` function.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new_with_school
    redirect_signed_in_user

    build_resource({})
    resource.build_school
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  def create_with_school
    redirect_signed_in_user

    build_resource(sign_up_params_with_school)    
    resource.school = School.new(sign_up_params_with_school[:school_attributes])
    resource.school.user = resource
    resource.role = 1
    resource.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if resource.save
        format.html { redirect_to after_sign_up_path_for(resource) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: resource }
      else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        set_minimum_password_length
        format.html { render :new_with_school }
        format.json { render json: resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  protected

    def redirect_signed_in_user
      redirect_to '/' if user_signed_in?
    end
end
```

I gave this error message:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

So it seems in Rails I can use only one redirect function in action.

But in this case, how can I achieve that if the user logged in, those 2 actions cannot reachable by the logged in user. The most beautiful solution will be, it the webapp could somehow redirect users to the root path (without throw an exception), so I want the most user friendly solution.

How can I do this? (I have read the devise code, but I cannot figure out how the root redirection works in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
def redirect_signed_in_user
      redirect_to '/' && return if user_signed_in?
end
```

Comment: Yes, this does not throw up any errors, but how can I force the return? Maybe I do something wrong, but the redirection does not work, it seems rails does not execute the redirect_to method. Yes, the `if user_signed_in?` is true, but i do not why the rails reading the next lines in the action, does not exit from the action after redirect.

Comment: just move this code in your main action       redirect_to '/' && return if user_signed_in?
. :)

Comment: What do you mean on 'main action'? :) I thought on application controller, but nothing, my actions still want to render theirs views.

Comment: my bad create_with_school action

Comment: Yeap, I figured out. It is funny the redirection works with this code only: `return redirect_to '/' if user_signed_in?`
Thank you :)